# How to get average of multiple lists within certain range in python?

Tags: python, list, average

I am trying to find a way to get an average of lists within a certain range. Say, I have 60 lists within a list and I would like to get an average of 10 lists and have 6 lists within a list. Is it possible to do that?

I know the code to get an average of lists (can't remember who wrote the code)

```
def average(l):
llen = len(l)
def divide(x):
    return x / llen
return map(divide, map(sum, zip(*l)))
```

Comment: What do you mean you "have 6 lists within a list?" Don't you have 60 lists?

Comment: @josh I meant [[5,4,5,8,7,6,9], [4,5,7,5,9,5,8], [4,4,2,1,5,14,2,5],.....................[60 length of lists]] to [[5,4,5,8,7,6,9], [4,5,7,5,9,5,8], [4,4,2,1,5,14,2,5], [1,5,4,7,9,2,4,5], [5,4,7,8,9,8,5,78], [1,2,5,4,6,8,25,8]] [6 length of lists]

Comment: So you want something like: `[ [average of lists 0-9], [average of lists 10-19], ..., [average of lists 50-59] ]` ?

Comment: @josh Yes, that's right

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).